# Cython read binary file into string and return

Tags: python, c, cython

Wondering how to read a binary file in Cython and return a string back to Python. I have the following but am getting an error on the fread(buffer..) line. I'm not super familiar with C/ Cython so if there are easier built in functions to read binary files into strings that would be appreciated

```
def read_file2(filename):
cdef FILE * cfile
cdef long length
filename_byte_string = filename.encode("UTF-8")
cdef char* fname = filename_byte_string
cdef char * buffer;

cfile = fopen(fname, "rb")
if cfile:
    fseek (cfile, 0, SEEK_END)
    length = ftell(cfile)
    fseek (cfile, 0, SEEK_SET)
    buffer = <char*>malloc(length)
    if buffer:
        fread(&buffer, 1, length, fname)
```

SOLVED: I get the following error:

```
read_numpy.pyx:64:33: Cannot assign type 'char *' to 'FILE *'
```

How do you return the buffer object, or string containing the byte representation of the file to Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistakenly used `fname` rather than `cfile`:

```
cfile = fopen(fname, "rb")
if cfile:
    fseek (cfile, 0, SEEK_END)
    length = ftell(cfile)
    fseek (cfile, 0, SEEK_SET)
    buffer = <char*>malloc(length)
    if buffer:
        fread(&buffer, 1, length, fname) <---
```

That final line should be:

```
  fread(&buffer, 1, length, cfile)
```